# Named pipes: several experiments leads to confusion

Tags: pipe, fifo

I've come across various articles and SO questions and I am still confused about something that I use on daily basis, but never realized how confusing it can be. I am experimenting with (named) pipes in Linux.

**1st**
try was simple: figure out how pipe buffers are working:

```
#1
mkfifo /tmp/mypipe
#2
echo "Hello World" >/tmp/mypipe
ctrl+c
#3
cat /tmp/mypipe
```

**Observation**:
When I killed `echo` before `cat` reads the data nothing was written to pipe (`cat` keeps running but nothing was read from pipe). I was assuming that when you type `producent >named_pipe` and you will exit `producent` then part of data that match pipe buffer size will be written to `named_pipe` and will remain here until it will be read by `consument` (now I know that this is not how it works). So what I did next was:

**2nd**
try was to connect `consument` to other end of pipe:

```
#1
mkfifo /tmp/mypipe
#2
echo "Hello World" >/tmp/mypipe
#3
cat /tmp/mypipe
```

**Observation**:
`cat` command displays the `"Hello World"` message and both processes ends. The interesting discovery here was that during the #2 step `ps -elf` does not display the `echo` command. It seems that `echo` is waiting until somebody will read from pipe and this is explanation why nothing was printed to pipe in my first attempt.

**3rd**
try was to pipe command that will run "forever" and constantly write to pipe and see what will happened:

```
#1
mkfifo /tmp/mypipe
#2
yes >/tmp/mypipe
#3
cat /tmp/mypipe
```

**Observation**:
This worked as expected and `cat` printed out what `yes` forwarded to pipe. However I have tried to replace `cat` with `tail -f`. When I did this then `tail` did not print anything until the `yes` command was killed.

**4th**
try is the big mystery:

```
# 1#
mkfifo /tmp/mypipe

# 2#
for i in $(seq 1 10000); do echo -n $i"|"> /tmp/mypipe; done

# 3#
for i in $(seq 1 10); do echo "${i}# Read:"; cat /tmp/mypipe && echo ""; done
```

After this the 3# command start typing something like that:

```
1# Read:
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|39|40|41|42|43|44|45|46|47|48|49|50|51|52|53|54|55|56|57|58|59|60|61|62|63|64|65|66|67|68|69|70|71|72|73|74|75|76|77|78|79|80|81|82|83|84|85|86|87|88|89|90|91|92|93|94|95|96|97|98|99|100|101|102|103|104|105|106|107|108|
2# Read:
109|
3# Read:
110|
4# Read:
111|
5# Read:
112|
6# Read:
113|114|115|
7# Read:
116|
8# Read:
117|
9# Read:
118|119|120|121|122|123|124|125|126|127|128|129|130|131|132|133|134|135|136|137|138|139|140|141|142|143|144|145|146|147|148|149|150|151|152|153|154|155|156|157|158|159|160|161|162|163|164|165|166|167|168|169|170|171|172|173|174|175|176|177|178|179|180|181|182|183|184|185|186|187|188|189|190|191|192|193|194|195|196|197|198|199|200|201|202|203|204|205|206|207|208|209|210|211|212|213|214|215|216|217|218|219|220|221|222|223|224|225|226|227|228|229|230|231|232|233|234|235|236|237|238|239|240|241|242|243|244|245|246|247|248|249|250|251|252|253|254|255|256|257|258|259|260|261|262|263|264|265|266|267|268|269|270|271|272|273|274|275|276|277|278|279|280|281|282|283|284|285|286|287|288|289|290|291|292|293|294|295|
10# Read:
296|297|298|299|300|301|302|303|304|305|306|307|308|309|310|311|312|313|314|315|316|317|318|319|320|321|322|323|324|325|326|327|328|329|
```

**Questions**:

**1st and 2nd try:**

1. Are the named pipes equivalent to classic `|` pipes as they are
   knows e.g. from bash in this particular case?
2. Does producent always wait for consument? If yes then what is purpose of pipe buffers? Is this behavior known as blocking communication?
3. How does Linux know when the consument is connected to pipe and thus when the communication can happen? I've tried `lsof named_pipe` but it gives me nothing, where is this information stored? I have also try following and result was that `cat` cannot read from pipe.

   ```
   #1
   mkfifo /tmp/mypipe
   #2
   echo 1 >/tmp/mypipe
   #3
   rm /tmp/mypipe
   #4
   mkfifo /tmp/mypipe
   #5
   cat /tmp/mypipe
   ```
4. Is typing: `producent >/tmp/mypipe`
   the equivalent of typing `command |` I mean the situation when somebody wants to pipe one command to another but forget to type another command after pipe (`ps` in this case also did not show first `command`)?

**3rd try:**

5. What is difference between `cat` and `tail -f` in this particular case?

**4th try**:

6. What is going on here? Why the chunks of read data are not the exact
   size? I was expecting output as:

   1# Read:
      1|
      2# Read:
      2|
      3# Read:
      3|

PS:
Also I have tried different order of starting commands (reading first and writing after) but the result was the same.

PPS:
I hope this is clear but:
Producer = process that writes to pipe.
Consumer = process that reads from pipe.

Is this possible explain to guy which has mostly scripting knowledge with bit of C? Thank you very much.

**EDIT in reply to: Joe Sewell**

1. OK Clear
  2.

I understand that both run in parallel, or in other words, following two are not the same:

```
find | less
```

vs

```
find > /tmp/file && less /tmp/file
```

My further observation discovers that, when I run following, HDD is not working seems that it is stopped until `less` command has enough data to display

```
find | less
```

When I hit `shifg+g` (go to the end of file in `less`) HDD starts immediately to work and data starts outputting. Does this mean that when `less` command has enough data to display it will somehow tell `find` to not produce further data? This is what you mean by synchronization? Also the amount of data writes to pipe corresponds to it buffer size? I have also noticed that `find` changes it state (`ps aux` - stat column) from `S+ to D+` after I hit `shift+g` in `less`

```
S    interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
D    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
+    is in the foreground process group.

┌─[wakatana@~] [63 files, 178Mb]
└──> ps aux | egrep -w 'less|find'
wakatana     6071  0.0  0.0  12736  1088 pts/5    S+   23:15   0:00 find
wakatana     6072  0.0  0.0   7940   928 pts/5    S+   23:15   0:00 less
wakatana     6183  0.0  0.0   7832   892 pts/6    S+   23:20   0:00 egrep --color=auto -w less|find
┌─[wakatana@~] [63 files, 178Mb]
└──> ps aux | egrep -w 'less|find'
wakatana     6071  0.0  0.0  12808  1304 pts/5    D+   23:15   0:00 find
wakatana     6072  0.0  0.0   9556  2508 pts/5    S+   23:15   0:00 less
wakatana     6193  0.0  0.0   7832   892 pts/6    S+   23:21   0:00 egrep --color=auto -w less|find
```

- Who sends this signal, consument to producent? If yes then how
  consument know that he is connected to the pipe which already has
  producent (e.g. my example with rm pipe)?
- OK Clear
- OK Clear
- I think that the new lines is not the case that confuses me. Based on my previous observations (and you confirmed that: "Yes, both ends wait for each other."). I was expecting this:
- I. 1st iteration in 1st loop will write to pipe and because nobody is
  reading it will wait here.
- II. When 2nd loop is issued then the data which were written by 1st
  loop in 1st iteration will be read, nothing more was written here so
  nothing more can be read.
- III. 2nd loop will wait for next data to be written by 1st loop or
  (because order no matter) 1st loop will wait until written data will
  be read by 2nd loop, and so on and so on.

Because of this I was expecting that one write will corresponds to one read. I was also verifying if loop is not running so I modified a bit original command to see if something will be printed to STDOUT even if consument wont be reading, but nothing was printed.

```
for i in $(seq 1 10000); do
  if [ $(( $i % 5 )) -eq 0 ]; then
    echo $i;
  else
    echo -n $i"|"> /tmp/mypipe;
  fi;
done
```

"Since the writing process isn't sending any newlines, the reader simply reads until it's told it got "enough.""

- Who will tell consument that he's got enough?

"In the first case it's probably because the fifo's buffer filled up,"

- How can I fill buffer if communication is blocked (as i described above)?

"and therefore got flushed through to the reader."

- What do you mean by this? Sorry for my english.

"While there are ways to make communication asynchronous ..."

- Can you please briefly describe what is the difference between asynchronous and synchronous in this case?

Answer (score 5):

To answer your list of questions by number:

1. Named pipes, a.k.a. fifos, are essentially equivalent to unnamed pipes generated by the shell. The big difference is that synchronization between the two ends is intuitive with the shell version, while named pipes as you seem to be using them require a bit of knowledge about what the shell is doing for you.
2. Yes, both ends wait for each other. The purpose of fifos, like shell pipes, is to pass output from one process to the input of another. They are **not** temporary files. I suspect that's where you're getting confused. In the case of a shell command like `cat somefile.txt | less`, **both** commands are running simultaneously as forked processes, with the pipe serving to synchronize the two. This can be modified, if memory serves, in C, but not as easily with shell commands.
3. Processes can receive signals when the other end of a pipe gets a connection, but more often than not the whole intent, as noted above, is to keep the two processes synchronized. The writer sends something, and it knows it can continue when the write operation completes.
4. `bash` and `tcsh` will not let you pipe "into oblivion." The command isn't even run.
5. `tail -f` has to read the entire stream until it gets an EOF, in this case on `stdin`, before it can display anything. In your experiment the end never appeared. `cat`, on the other hand, can start working on its input immediately.
6. Since the writing process isn't sending any newlines, the reader simply reads until it's told it got "enough." In the first case it's probably because the fifo's buffer filled up, and therefore got flushed through to the reader. The subsequent output is probably similar, and will probably vary based on system timing.

Let me address another bit of confusion here. The shell handles redirection **before** a command is run. That means that you wouldn't see `cat` in a list of processes, because `bash` is stuck waiting for the other end of the fifo to connect **before** running `cat` or whatever writer is involved. Likewise it won't execute the reading command until the writer is connected.

I think the biggest misunderstanding you have here is that named pipes are **not** temporary files. Neither are unnamed pipes. While there are ways to make communication asynchronous, it looks like you'd be better off creating actual temporary files under `/tmp`, unless you **do** want both processes running simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

```
find | less
```

*When I hit `shift+g` (go to the end of file in `less`) HDD starts immediately to work and data starts outputting. Does this mean that when `less` command has enough data to display it will somehow tell `find` to not produce further data?*

No. Pipes work on `read()`s and `write()`s. `less` tells `find` *nothing* - but the system kernel which owns that pipe will not flush it as long as there is a `read()`ing process associated with it. So `find` `write()`s until it can `write()` no more because the pipe buffer fills up and the kernel does not accept another `write()`. So `find` is *block*ed. When you skip to the end of the pipe input `less` `read()`s the pipe and drains some - *(all)* - of that pipe buffer so `find` can now `write()` again - and so it does. It resumes its search of your disk and attempts to once more fill that buffer or complete its work.

The same is true of *named pipes* - which are the exact same thing - except that the kernel consents to associating both ends of the pipe with a pseudo-file - a *link* - somewhere in the filesystem. When you:

```
mkfifo pipe
echo > pipe &
rm pipe
mkfifo pipe
cat pipe
```

...you're working with *two different* pipes. The first was associated with a file-system name that was `unlink()`ed by `rm` - but `echo` still waits for a `read()`er on its pipe - though it is highly unlikely any process will be able to find the other end now. In fact, you can essentially make a named pipe anonymous in this way while still using it - which is usually best practice for security reasons.

Try:

```
   mkfifo pipe
   exec 3<>pipe 4<>pipe
   cat  <&3     >out.log &
   rm pipe
   echo read this, cat\! >&4
```

Comment: Three questions: 1. whole communication management between processes through pipes is kernel business? 2. Pipe buffer is used when both clients are connected to pipe (e.g. piping to oblivion)? 3. Pipe has it's own capacity and when producent is writing to pipe and consument is not reading then pipe buffer is full and kernel will block producent until consument will read the buffer?

Comment: @WakanTanka - For 1, probably  yes. And the same is true for all other files. Basically anything with an inode is the kernel's sole property. The pipe buffer is different though. What you're thinking about is probably the lib c actually - most progs will withhold `write()`s until they have buffered enough output to make some few kb at least of data per `write()` - the lib C does that, and it saves on system calls. The kernel also limits the pipe buffer though - pipes are only *so big* and so the kernel will only guarante atomic `writes()` of so much data at a time. I think 2|3 are the same q?